# Access-Control-Allow-Origin multiple values with Spring Boot and Vue.JS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js

I have this class for CORS on my API:

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

    @Configuration
    public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");

 }
}
```

Request returns me 200, and this is my answer to frontend:

> [Date:"Wed, 10 Jul 2019 18:11:54 GMT", Server:"Apache/2.4.18
>   (Ubuntu)", Vary:"Authorization", Cache-Control:"no-cache, private",
>   X-Robots-Tag:"noindex", Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*",
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:"POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS",
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"Authorization, Content-Type, Accept",
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:"true", Keep-Alive:"timeout=5,
>   max=100", Connection:"Keep-Alive", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked",
>   Content-Type:"application/json"]

But in my console at chrome I see:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/empresas'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,
>   *', but only one is allowed.

My controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "empresas", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity listaEmpresa(@NotNull @RequestHeader String authorization) throws IOException {
    tokenValidatorService.validaToken(authorization);
    return companyModel.listaEmpresas(authorization);
}
```

What can I do? I don't set up Access Control Allow Origin anytime at my code..

Comment: You can simply put the @CrossOrigin at the beginning of your method.

Comment: Hi, Sudar. No results with @CrossOrigin. I'll add my controller if it help

Comment: Looks like you might have another Filter or something that's also adding that header as well -- might be worth running with debug logging to see if you can find what might be adding a second Access-Control-Allow-Origin header of *. I ran into this issue with a misconfigured websocket server and a Spring Cloud gateway.

Comment: Some point inside Spring is adding this header, but I dunno how to configure it to NOT do this

Comment: Hi, I am having same error about CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values. In my case, it is Spring Boot REST API and Angular client talking to it. All API endpoints are working fine. But one of them calls another API which adds its own CORS and returns it in response header therefore response returned from my API ends up having multiple values. How would I address this? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this configuration and it works.

Be sure that `@Configuration` class is loaded in application context

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you have a security mechanism that trigger pre-flight request, you have also to allow `HttpMethod.OPTIONS` calls on all your application as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class KsSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")    // <---------- You need this
                .antMatchers(
                        "/**/*.{js,html,css,ico}",
                        "/i18n/**",
                        "/assets/**",
                        "/v2/api-docs/**",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Hi, ValerioMC. What do you mean by "Be sure that @Configuration class is loaded in application context"? Can you demonstrate it?

Also, I've used your class... same error...

Comment: @FearX it’s possibile that your class is not loaded by spring boot application. Did you put class in a subpackage of SpringBoot entrypoint class? If youhave doubts you can put a logger and check it ah startup

Comment: updated answer allowing also pre-flight requests `HttpMethod.OPTIONS`

Answer (score 1):

If your are using spring-cloud-gateway api then try below

spring:
cloud:
gateway:
globalcors:
corsConfigurations:
'[/*]':
allowed-origins: "*"
allowed-methods: "*"
allowed-headers: "*"
allow-credentials: true

```
  routes:
  - id: login-users
    uri: http://localhost:1000/
    filters:
    - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    predicates:
    - Path=/login/v1/post/login
    - Method=POST
  - id: loginservice
    uri: http://localhost:1001/
    predicates:
    - Path=/login/v1/**
    - Method=POST
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error in following scenario.

I have Springboot RESTAPI and Angular client.

Angular Client calls the API and all end points are behaving as expected.

**CAUSE (IN MY SCENARIO)**

However, one endpoint in my API calls another API.

That other API returns response including the headers containing its own Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Then my API adds its own Access-Control-Allow-Origin resulting in two Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers which is not allowed by browsers.

My CORS settings are right because I know all other endpoints are working fine and are returning only one Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @RobbyofTheFozenPeas So, the solution I did is that in the Controller calling other API, and once other API returns response, I would get the body out of that response and create a new ResponseEntity from it.

This results in only my API returning its own Access-Control-Allow-Origin and all is working fine.

I hope this explanation of the cause and solution will help others since I see lots of people are asking the same question.